# Do not run integration tests when running mvn clean install

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I want the following to happen:

- when I run `mvn clean install` , I want unit tests alone to run (no integration tests)
- When I do `mvn integration test` , I want integration test alone to run (no unit tests)
- when I do `mvn test` unit test alone should run.

I tried few things with `Maven Surefire` plugin and `Maven failsafe` plugin but could not 
achieve this. What I have tried is: added Surefire and Failsafe plugins, tried separating the unit tests with annotations, as well separating unit and integration tests at package level, and keeping specific naming convention for unit and integration test.

What I am able to achieve is run unit tests alone on `mvn clean install`, but when I run Maven integration test I am not able to stop unit tests from running. Any idea how I should go about it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have that you don't understand the [Maven life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) which has the following phases (only excerpts):

```
   clean
   ...
   compile
   ...
   test
   ..
   pre-integration-test
   integration-test
   post-integration-test
   ..
   install
```

This means in other words your requirement to do `mvn clean install` without running the integration tests is not satisfiable by the defaults (conventions).

I would suggest to create a profile where you put the maven-failsafe-plugin into so you can control if integration-tests will run or not. This results into a thing like this:

```
mvn -Prun-its install
```

to run the integration tests you can use the following:

```
mvn verify
```

which will include running the unit tests but this can be suppressed by using:

```
mvn -DskipTests=true verify
```

Using `mvn test` will run only the unit tests no integration tests cause it's earlier in life cycle.

Comment: I agree with you on maven life cycle, but when i configure a sure fire plugin ( maven will use mine instead of the default  plugin ) to run tests, I have configured my sure fire plugin and have specifed few packages,classes in the <excludes>,<excludeGroup> , those are not being honored. Basically i do have problem with when test or integration test is being ran. What i want is when mvn test is being done, maven/surefire should not ignore  the configurations i have specified.

Comment: So if the configuration you have made is not honoured you should show your pom file?